# Delegation Error for Kerberos for Specific Windows Workstation

Tags: windows, kerberos, kerberos-delegation

I am having an workstation specific Kerberos issue and hope anyone here would have additional recommendation.

Our application has an application server and web server and we have kerberos configured on both application layer and web layer.

And for certain users, when we provide the Kerberos link and they are not able to authorize in. And we found out the issue is **workstation specific**. And on the same problematic workstation, the user could access application server via Kerberos authentication.

And on the web logic we see the following error:

[SpnegoFilter.doFilter] Although user authentication to xxx was successful, Integrated Authentication could not extract the user's credentials because it appears delegation was either not configured or disallowed

I am looking for any of Windows setting could potential lead to this issue? We check that our domain is trusted on both working and nonworking machines on the browser level and GPO settings are the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is unconstrained delegation, which is the act of a user handing the remote server their TGT so the server can impersonate the user without restriction.

Windows deems this as incredibly dangerous (it is) and is moving towards disabling it outright when certain security services are enabled on the client. [Specifically Credential Guard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/identity-protection/credential-guard/credential-guard-considerations#kerberos-considerations). It will also block it for users that are members of the [Protected Users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/security/credentials-protection-and-management/protected-users-security-group) security group, though the fact that it's affecting specific workstations leans towards Credential Guard.

If it is the above issues the correct solution is to switch to *[constrained delegation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/askds/understanding-kerberos-double-hop#constrained-vs-general-delegation)*.

Comment: Thanks. It is worth to try. The only thing I feel odd is on the same machine, the user could authenticate into the application server using the application tool via kerberos but not via web.

Comment: The tool may not be invoking a path that uses unconstrained delegation or it's an entirely different problem. There's not a whole lot of information here to say one way or another what it's actually doing.